# custom post types wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am wanting to create a custom post type called testimonials, for this I am wanting to allow the administrator that chance to add a company name/username and what testimonial they have given, I understand I can do this by declaring a custom post-type in my `functions.php` file, however it does not seem to work and all I get is the normal post fields, can someone tell me where I am going wrong, or how I would do this please?

```
 function testimonials_register() {
 $args = array(
  'label' => __('Testimonials'),
  'singular_label' => __('Testimonial'),
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'capability_type' => false,
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'rewirte' => true,
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor')
 );

 register_post_type('testimonial', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You spelled rewrite wrong, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `add_action('init', 'testimonials_regiser');` afer the function.

A more thorough code that's a bit more customized can be as follows:

```
function testimonials_register() {
$labels = array(
'name'               => _x( 'Testimonials', 'post type general name' ),
'singular_name'      => _x( 'Testimonial', 'post type singular name' ),
'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'testimonial' ),
'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Testimonial' ),
'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Testimonial' ),
'new_item'           => __( 'New Testimonial' ),
'all_items'          => __( 'All Testimonials' ),
'view_item'          => __( 'View Testimonial' ),
'search_items'       => __( 'Search Testimonials' ),
'not_found'          => __( 'No testimonials found' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No testimonials found in the Trash' ), 
'parent_item_colon'  => '',
'menu_name'          => 'Testimonial'
);
$args = array(
'labels'        => $labels,
'description'   => '',
'public'        => true,
'menu_position' => 5,
'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor'),
'has_archive'   => true,
);
register_post_type( 'testimonial', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'testimonials_register' );
```

Here is a good [guide](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/complete-guide-custom-post-types/).